# @MessageMapping not trigger controller when message push from Javascript via WebSocket

Tags: websocket, stomp, sockjs, spring-websocket

I am try to do the WebSocket demo using Spring 4.1.1, Stomp 2.3.3, sockjs 0.3.4

On server side : 
There is a config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class AppWebSocketConfig extends
        AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

And the is a controller to proccess the message

```
@Controller
public class EBConsoleWebSocketController {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(EBConsoleWebSocketController.class);

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        LOG.info(message.getName());
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

    public class HelloMessage implements Serializable {

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    public class Greeting implements Serializable {
        private String content;

        public Greeting(String content) {
            super();
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

    }
}
```

**The problem is seem the @MessageMapping do not trigger greeting method.**

Here is the client side javascript.

```
var stompClient = null;

    function setConnected(connected) {
        document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
        document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
        document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
    }

    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS("<c:url value='/hello'/>");
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting) {
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        if (stompClient != null) {
            stompClient.disconnect();
        }
        setConnected(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }

    function sendName() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({
            'name' : name
        }));
    }

    function showGreeting(message) {
        var response = document.getElementById('response');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        response.appendChild(p);
    }
```

Comment: There should be some network interaction anyway. I'd suggest to switch on `DEBUG` for `org.springframework` on the server and take a look to the network traffic using sniffer tool. Modern Browser have some plugin on the matter. I don't see anything critical, unless that `<c:url value='/hello'/>`, which you can change to the real ULR for development.

Comment: the <c:url output is /integration/hello where integration is my context path. Seem correct.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Show your `DispatcherServlet` configuration. Any progress with debug?